# why does the "celery" queue appear in sqs when deploying to beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

Every time I deploy to a beanstalk, I run celery workers, each of which is configured for a specific queue, and logs are also configured for each worker separately.[image]

The question is where does this queue come from and why does everything work? why do workers that are configured for other queues successfully process tasks from this one?

Below some example of my celery services.

```
echo "[Unit]
Description=Celery
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
WorkingDirectory=/var/app/current
ExecStart=$PYTHONPATH/celery -A MyApp worker -Q default-dev -n default-worker \
         --logfile=/var/log/celery/path-to-log --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
" | tee /etc/systemd/system/celery-default.service

## Service 'celery-broadcats' ('broadcasts-dev' queue)
echo "[Unit]
Description=Celery
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
WorkingDirectory=/var/app/current
ExecStart=$PYTHONPATH/celery -A MyApp worker -Q broadcasts-dev -n broadcast-worker \
         --logfile=/var/log/celery/path-to-logs --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
" | tee /etc/systemd/system/celery-broadcats.service
```

Comment: My understanding is that some internal Celery tasks are sent to the default ("celery") queue. Name of this queue is controlled with the [task_default_queue](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.0.1/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_default_queue) configuration parameter. Also, if you call send_task(), or delay() or apply_async() but do not specify the queue name, it will go to the default ("celery") queue, which explains why your "celery" queue was busy. You need to do something like `mytask.apply_async(args, queue="broadcast-dev")`

Comment: @DejanLekic doesn't this configuration affect queues? app.conf.task_routes = {
    'main_app.tasks.send_flow_to_subscribers': {
        'queue': sequences,
        'serializer': 'json',
        'routing_key': 'main_app.tasks.send_flow_to_subscribers'
    },
  ...
}

Comment: Nope, it just changes the name of the default queue, which you _must_ have as far as I know.